# How do I do dot inside a letter?

Tags: support, mathjax

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Ch9.1

> [image]

Circle: `$C[z_0,R] = |z-z_0| = R$`

Disc: `$D[z_0,R] = |z-z_0| < R$`

Closed Disc: `$\overline{D}[z_0,R] = |z-z_0| \le R$`

Punctured disc: `$0 < |z-z_0| < R$`

How do I do the dot inside the `$D$` to denote a punctured disc?

Comment: In my opinion, that is a *terrible* choice of notation.

Comment: @mrf thanks I guess XD

Comment: I am in agreement with @mrf.  That notation is awful–the little dot doesn't really jump out at me, and the profile of the letter isn't changed at all.  I might suggest something like $$D^* \qquad\text{or}\qquad \dot D\qquad\text{or}\qquad D_\circ \qquad\text{or}\qquad D'$$ or the like instead.  One thing that you should learn early in your mathematical career is not to slavishly follow the notation of others when their notation is clearly not very good. :)

Comment: @XanderHenderson THANKS XD

Comment: @XanderHenderson ...clearly not very good *and you have no idea how to reproduce it*!

Comment: @user1729 Right-click on the math.  [Show Math As] $\to$ [TeX Command].

Comment: You might want to add a link to the same question you asked on Tex StackEschange.

Comment: @Xander I was referring to the notation in the question, which the OP could not reproduced, rather than your comment (whose suggestions are good because they are clear and use pretty standard commands to reproduce).

Comment: As per @PeterPhipps comment, this has been cross-posted on [tex.se]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446253/how-do-i-do-dot-inside-a-letter

Comment: @PeterPhipps thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$D\!\!\!\!\cdot$$

For example.

Comment: Or ${D\kern-5pt\bullet}\kern2pt$ (using `${D\kern-5pt\bullet}\kern2pt$`)?  Still terrible notation, if you ask me, but the bullet is a bit easier to read, methinks.

Comment: @Xander: ${D\kern-5pt{\tiny\bullet}}\kern2pt$ is slightly better. Now the vertical alignment is off, though.

Comment: Indeed, that is marginally better.  Still terrible notation. ;)

Comment: Yes. Very terrible, @Xander.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thanks for both the notation and the support XD